# /laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/MySqlConnection.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, mysql, composer-php

I saw that MySqlConnection.php is missing from the folder shown in the error. Inspect console shows this - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error). I am running this locally on Ubuntu 20
Do I have to create a MySqlconnection.php file ?

PLease help...thank you...

Comment: Shown in which error? How is this problem related to MySQL itself, or Composer?

Comment: From the error;I followed the path and mysqlconnection.php is missing. I thought to myself mysql could be the error; but had the same thought how is it mysql error?